# Calling a Java SOAP Web Service by WCF Client

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

I am calling a Java SOAP web service using WCF client (and Service Reference approach) - I am getting the following exception while trying to create an instance of the service client:

```
Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'name of the service' 
in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration 
file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract 
could be found in the client element.
```

Very little has been generated in the web config:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="***SOAP" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

---

I also tried Service Reference=> Adnanced=>Web Reference which failed with:

```
{"Unable to connect to the remote server"}
```

---

Is Service Reference a cul-de-sac route when calling non-WCF web services or how do I get it working otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Can you call the WSDL (http://....?wsdl) inside the browser? The WSDL file is the contract how describe, what the web service provide (method with parameter and return value), and on which way you get access to the service. - http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl